# Precision in Golang

Tags: math, go

I'm trying to do the following calculation:
28860.000000001 - 28800 = 60.000000001

However Go gives me 60.000000001000444

```
a := float64(28860.000000001)
b := float64(28800)
expected := float64(60.000000001)
answer := a - b
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this inherit with floats. Read more here:
http://floating-point-gui.de/